# Why does this reduce evaluate with exact numbers but not numbers specified to 20/50/200 decimals of precision?

Tags: equation-solving, number-representation, precision-and-accuracy

Consider the following lines of code:

```
Reduce[2 Log[x + 1] + Log[3 - x + 1] == 
  2 Log[2.8 + 1] + Log[.2 + 1], x]

Reduce[2 Log[x + 1] + Log[3 - x + 1] == 
  2 Log[2.8`20 + 1] + Log[.2`20 + 1], x]

Reduce[2 Log[x + 1] + Log[3 - x + 1] == 
  2 Log[2.8`50 + 1] + Log[.2`50 + 1], x]

Reduce[2 Log[x + 1] + Log[3 - x + 1] == 
  2 Log[2.8`200 + 1] + Log[.2`200 + 1], x]

Reduce[2 Log[x + 1] + Log[3 - x + 1] == 
  2 Log[N[2.8, 200] + 1] + Log[N[.2, 200] + 1], x]
```

None of those evaluate (mathematica just returns the command, with whatever digits of precision are specified on the numbers)

The code exectutes with exact numbers though:

```
Reduce[2 Log[x + 1] + Log[3 - x + 1] == 
  2 Log[28/10 + 1] + Log[2/10 + 1], x]

Reduce[2 Log[x + 1] + Log[3 - x + 1] == 
  2 Log[Rationalize[2.8] + 1] + Log[Rationalize[.2] + 1], x]
```

**Why do the first few examples not execute but the latter two do? I was thinking that the problem is the numbers not being precise enough**

- but if that's the case are 200 digit arbitrary precision numbers really not enough precision (`N[2.8,200]` or `.2(backtick)200` representation)

Comment: `N` does not do what you apparently think that it does. Note that  `N[0.2, 200]` is just `0.2` and `Precision[N[0.2, 200]]` evaluates to `MachinePrecision`. `N` never increases the precision of its argument. To increase the precision of `0.2`, use `SetPrecision[0.2, 200]` or as you already did, `0.2\`200` You can solve the inexact equation with either `Solve` or `NSolve`

Comment: @BobHanlon I know `Solve` and `NSolve` work. I am wondering why `Reduce` is not working, though? If the issue is that `Reduce` does not want me to use `MachinePrecision` numbers, why does `Reduce[2 Log[x + 1] + Log[3 - x + 1] == 2.85, x]` Evaluate? Also, Thanks for clarifying that about `N`; I am still getting my head wrapped around `Precision`, and how it is handled

Comment: `MachinePrecision` equations (even of the same general form) are not all of the same level of difficulty to solve to the level of precision needed. `2 Log[2.8 + 1] + Log[.2 + 1] // Rationalize[#, 0] &` evaluates to `167513191/58728675` as opposed to `2.85//Rationalize[#, 0]&` which is just `57/20`

Comment: @BobHanlon Okay, that makes sense. I will stick to using exact equations in `Reduce` and using `Solve` or `NSolve` for inexact equations. Out of curiosity, though, do you know if `Reduce` tries changing `MachinePrecision` numbers to exact or arbitrary precision numbers then? I tried looking at this with `Trace[]` but I can't tell.

Comment: The warning messages states in part "Reduce::inex: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system." The **direct rationalization** would produce exact numbers; however, not necessarily the same exact numbers as manually converting depending on how it is done. `2 Log[14/5 + 1] + Log[1/5 + 1]` is an exact number and works; whereas, just rationalizing the RHS (which is presumably what `Reduce` tried) doesn't.

Comment: I cannot go back further than v12.0, the message is there with it. If you see `Reduce::inex` evaluate `Message[Reduce::inex]` to see the full message.